# Decrypting a form always returns the previous authentication ticket values

Tags: security, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC application that uses Active Directory membership for user authentication.

After the user logs in, a `FormsAuthenticatedTicket` is created and encrypted. Then, in `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` the ticket is decrypted and the deserialized user data is stored in a custom principal object.

My problem is that when a user logs in after their cookie has expired, the ticket is encrypted with the current login data, but in global.asax the previous login's ticket is still decrypted. When debugging, I have seen the ticket data of the previous login of the same user with version 2.

What mistake did I make?

Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login">
  </forms>
</authentication>

<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">  
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="ADMembershipProvider" 
  type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
  connectionStringName ="ADconnectionString"
  attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />  

</providers>  
</membership>
```

my post action login method

```
  [HttpPost]
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
  {

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
    {
        ViewBag.Message = FormattedMessage.GetFormattedMessage("Veuillez Entrer l'utilisateur et/ou mot passe", TypeMessage.Danger, true);
        return this.View();
    }

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, rememberMe);
        //JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain); 
        var userAD = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userName);
        var intervenant = unitOfWorkBll.UserBLL.GetAllFiltered(u => u.Matricule == userAD.EmployeeId, includes: "IntervenantRoles.Role, IntervenantStructures.Structure").SingleOrDefault();
        //string userData = js.Serialize(intervenant);
        string userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(intervenant, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
        });
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),rememberMe, userData);

        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl) )
        {
            return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    ViewBag.Message= FormattedMessage.GetFormattedMessage("l'utilisateur et /ou le mot passe incorrect.", TypeMessage.Danger, true);

    return this.View();
}
```

global.asax

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie autoCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (autoCookie != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(autoCookie.Value);
        Intervenant user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Intervenant>(ticket.UserData/*, new JsonSerializerSettings {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
        }*/);

        CustomADPrincipal customADPrincipal = new CustomADPrincipal(user); ;

        HttpContext.Current.User = customADPrincipal;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have edited your question to make it more clear. That being said, your question is currently off topic for two reasons. (1) it does not work; This site is only for reviewing working code. (2) you mention that you don't understand how it works; this site requires that you be the owner/maintainer of the code, and understand why it is implemented the way it is. As such I've voted to close as off topic. Please [edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/232081/edit) your question once you're able to address these issues.